# Select fixed-size connected induced subgraphs in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, connected

I have a connected graph with $nk$ vertices, and would like to select $n$ disjoint induced subgraphs with $k$ vertices such that each subgraph is connected, selecting one out of all possible solutions at random. It doesn't necessarily need to be *uniformly* at random, I just want the possibility of getting any possible solution.

For example, with this graph:

[image: a cycle of 4 vertices, sharing 1 vertex with a cycle of 3 vertices]

and $k=3$, $n=2$, here is a solution (in fact it's the only one):

[image: the vertices in the 3-cycle are grouped together, and so are the remaining 3 vertices]

And here's one of the two possible solutions for the same graph with $k = 2$ and $n = 3$:

[image: two pairs of vertices in the 4-cycle are grouped together, as are the remaining 2 vertices]

Sometimes this is not possible, like with this graph, for $k = 3$ and $n = 2$:

[image: a path of 4 vertices, with a path of 2 vertices coming out of the second vertex]

Is there any (efficient) way of determining whether there is a solution, and if so, selecting one (not necessarily uniformly) at random?

Comment: Checking whether the partition exists is NP-hard: ["On the complexity of partitioning graphs into connected subgraphs"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X85900083) has some references and shows that this holds even for planar graphs.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks! I figured this had already been looked into before, but wasn't sure what to google...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unfortunately NP-hard.
Thanks to Dmitry for finding this:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X85900083.